# Footer exceeding width of screen with sliding vertical navbar

Tags: html, css, footer

So I have a vertical sliding navbar and the rest of the content flows next to it with right width. Although, I am having a lot of trouble with the footer. I want it to sit at the bottom of the page regardless of how much content is on the page.

```
   <footer class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="">link</a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="">link</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </footer>

   //css
   html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
   }

   .legal {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
   }
```

Because I want the footer sitting at the bottom ive set it to absolute, but because its inheriting its width from the content above and being pushed across from the navbar its exceeding the screen by the width of the navbar. But if I was to set a left margin for it when the navbar collapsed with the screen size changing it will still sit with the margin and be out of position. Is there anyway to have it still sit at the bottom without making it absolute? Even with the content above set to 100% height when I make it relative it still isn't at the bottom. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can u plz send this code codepen or fiddle?

Comment: Can you share shcreenshot for what you expect?

Comment: can you please share codepen for the same

Comment: you didn't provide full code and output. Unable to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide many details about the code or any screenshot of the problem, I can't really tell you how you can fix the overflowing width issue but here are something you can try:

- Try setting box-sizing to border-box
- To make the footer stick to the bottom, you can try multiple options like, making the position fixed and bottom 0 and adding a bottom margin to the rest of the upper content to which should exactly be equal to the max height of the footer.
- You can move everything in a flex container and only make the content area scrollable with the overflow property with flex set to 1 (flex: 1; flex-flow: column).
- You can set the height of the content container to 100vh so it will always be expanded and will keep the footer to the bottom.

For the width overflow issue, try making sure the text is using "white-space: nowrap" property so it won't set footer items min-width to the text width. Or, try setting overflow X / Y to hidden so the expanded content doesn't show outside the container. If you're using flex, try using Flex-wrap so Flex can automatically adust the component to the container's width.

Hope it helps!